# How can I both load my Simulink model to my Arduino and add also my own code with it?

Tags: matlab, arduino, embed, simulink

I can perfectly build simulink models and upload it to my Arduino. But I need some more code that I customly create by myself. So how can I add my own custom code with matlab simulink code as well?

In other words, is there a way to get `c++` code of the simulink model including `Arduino Hardware Support Blocks` and make some changes and add some more code and upload it myself?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/simulink/c-c-s-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what code you are trying to add there are different approaches:

1. Already mentioned by am304, the [Custom Code](http://www.mathworks.com/help/rtw/ref/code-generation-pane-custom-code.html) option in the Configuration Paramters
2. With custom [S-Functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/c-c-s-functions.html) you write your own blocks with code that gets included in the model. (You may need to learn [TLC](http://www.mathworks.com/help/rtw/block-authoring-with-tlc.html))
3. A more manual approach is customizing the [Template Makefile](http://www.mathworks.com/help/rtw/ug/customizing-template-makefiles.html) to compile your source files, together with the generated source code from the model.
4. The main file (rt_main.c) can also be customized.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. If my memory serves me well, it's in `Configuration Parameters -> Code Generation -> Custom Code`. You can include custom code in source files, header files, initialize function and terminate function. You can also include a list of additional include directories, source files and libraries.

Comment: Thank you very much.This answer gave me insight.